# Downloading a large file (~500 Mb) to local storage from FTP, without breaking the server

Tags: php, laravel

I'm required to download a large XML file from a remote FTP server to local storage so that I can process it.

I've defined an FTP driver that can access the file. However, because of the size of the file, PHP gives up allocating memory for the operation.

`Storage::disk('ftp')->get('path/to/file/bigass.xml');`

Is there any way that doesn't eat up memory and can download file without issues?

Comment: can you share how you implemented the get($filename) method?

Comment: give this a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597159/downloading-large-files-reliably-in-php

Comment: @SimonlucaLandi - it's the regular Laravel `get` method. No customisation.

Comment: please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509440/increase-the-limit-of-file-download-size-in-document-management-system

Comment: can i know the error message you are getting

Comment: try this lib which supports streams i believe https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/adapter/sftp/

Comment: also check this answer which uses flysystem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020515/phpleague-flysystem-read-and-write-to-large-file-on-server

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to switch to a "plain old" curl solution, using something like this:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$fh   = fopen("localfilename.xml", 'w');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://{$ftp_username}:{$ftp_password}@{$ftp_server}/path/to/file/bigass.xml");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
fwrite($fh, $result);
fclose($fh);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: How does it work differently? I mean, Does curl support streaming?